# Multiple conditions in IF statement how to

Tags: c#

**EDIT:**

Sorry i should of been more clear and given a clearer example of what i'm trying to achieve.

So i'll try explain again

I have a if statement which checks 2 scenarios (either of them can match)

`if((variable1 == false || variable2 == "Sales")){
   //Do something
}`

I need to add an another scenario (the first 2 above should remain as is and the new logic to add is another scenario which might happen)

I now need to check that:
variable3 < 10 
AND
variable4 == null

So variable3 has to be <10 AND variable4 must be null

so far i tried

`if( (variable1 == false || variable2 == "Sales") || (variable3 < 10 && variable4 == null) ){
   //Do something
}`

but it didn't work?

Comment: Is this for c# or php?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want.  Do you need one of the first two _and_ both of the second two?  Or do you need one of the first two _or_ both of the second two.  Your words potentially contradict your code.

Comment: sorry i've added an edit which should help

Comment: And in what way did your attempt not do what you want?  What happened that shouldn't have happened, or what didn't happen that should have?

Comment: It looks like you implemented it correctly. Can you be more specific than "it didn't work"? Specifically, what unexpected behavior are you seeing, what's the behavior you're expecting, and why are you expecting that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

```
variable3 == true && variable4 == null

(variable3 == true && variable4 == true)
```

You've got the right idea, except you are testing two different things in the posted code. The first checks varaible4 is null, and the code example checks for true. Looks like a simple typo.

Also, instead of, for example:

```
if(variable3 == true)
```

You can simply write:

```
if(variable3)
```

when you want to test that a bool is true.

So it sounds like the code you want is:

```
if (variable1 || variable2 || (variable3 && variable4 == null))
```

Comment: Looks like an off-topic typo question if this is the answer.

Comment: See edit above (it should be clearer)

Comment: @marjfh67 from your edited code your logic is fine, from what information we have. Step through it with a debugger and see what values are different to what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```cs
(variable1 == true || variable2 === true) && (variable3 == true && variable4 == true)
```

This way, both `(variable1 == true || variable2 === true)` and `(variable3 == true && variable4 == true)` need to be true.